# Error in the installation step

Tags: doxygen

I just tried to install doxygen. I am using OSX and I just executed make and I got this error message:

```
/usr/bin/make -f Makefile.libdoxygen all
c++ -c -pipe -D__FreeBSD__=6 -DYY_TYPEDEF_YY_SIZE_T -Dyy_size_t=int -Wall -W -Wno-deprecated-declarations -O2 -I../qtools -I../libmd5 -o ../objects/context.o context.cpp
context.cpp: In constructor 'ClassContext::Private::Private(ClassDef*)':
context.cpp:957: error: class 'ClassContext::Private' does not have any field named 'DefinitionContext'
context.cpp:959: error: no matching function for call to 'DefinitionContext<ClassContext::Private>::DefinitionContext()'
context.cpp:714: note: candidates are: DefinitionContext<T>::DefinitionContext(Definition*) [with T = ClassContext::Private]
context.cpp:712: note:                 DefinitionContext<ClassContext::Private>::DefinitionContext(const DefinitionContext<ClassContext::Private>&)
context.cpp: In constructor 'NamespaceContext::Private::Private(NamespaceDef*)':
context.cpp:1559: error: class 'NamespaceContext::Private' does not have any field named 'DefinitionContext'
context.cpp:1559: error: no matching function for call to 'DefinitionContext<NamespaceContext::Private>::DefinitionContext()'
context.cpp:714: note: candidates are: DefinitionContext<T>::DefinitionContext(Definition*) [with T = NamespaceContext::Private]
context.cpp:712: note:                 DefinitionContext<NamespaceContext::Private>::DefinitionContext(const DefinitionContext<NamespaceContext::Private>&)
context.cpp: In constructor 'FileContext::Private::Private(FileDef*)':
context.cpp:1604: error: class 'FileContext::Private' does not have any field named 'DefinitionContext'
context.cpp:1604: error: no matching function for call to 'DefinitionContext<FileContext::Private>::DefinitionContext()'
context.cpp:714: note: candidates are: DefinitionContext<T>::DefinitionContext(Definition*) [with T = FileContext::Private]
context.cpp:712: note:                 DefinitionContext<FileContext::Private>::DefinitionContext(const DefinitionContext<FileContext::Private>&)
context.cpp: In constructor 'DirContext::Private::Private(DirDef*)':
context.cpp:1654: error: class 'DirContext::Private' does not have any field named 'DefinitionContext'
context.cpp:1654: error: no matching function for call to 'DefinitionContext<DirContext::Private>::DefinitionContext()'
context.cpp:714: note: candidates are: DefinitionContext<T>::DefinitionContext(Definition*) [with T = DirContext::Private]
context.cpp:712: note:                 DefinitionContext<DirContext::Private>::DefinitionContext(const DefinitionContext<DirContext::Private>&)
context.cpp: In constructor 'PageContext::Private::Private(PageDef*)':
context.cpp:1705: error: class 'PageContext::Private' does not have any field named 'DefinitionContext'
context.cpp:1705: error: no matching function for call to 'DefinitionContext<PageContext::Private>::DefinitionContext()'
context.cpp:714: note: candidates are: DefinitionContext<T>::DefinitionContext(Definition*) [with T = PageContext::Private]
context.cpp:712: note:                 DefinitionContext<PageContext::Private>::DefinitionContext(const DefinitionContext<PageContext::Private>&)
context.cpp: In constructor 'MemberContext::Private::Private(MemberDef*)':
context.cpp:1860: error: class 'MemberContext::Private' does not have any field named 'DefinitionContext'
context.cpp:1860: error: no matching function for call to 'DefinitionContext<MemberContext::Private>::DefinitionContext()'
context.cpp:714: note: candidates are: DefinitionContext<T>::DefinitionContext(Definition*) [with T = MemberContext::Private]
context.cpp:712: note:                 DefinitionContext<MemberContext::Private>::DefinitionContext(const DefinitionContext<MemberContext::Private>&)
context.cpp: In constructor 'ModuleContext::Private::Private(GroupDef*)':
context.cpp:2235: error: class 'ModuleContext::Private' does not have any field named 'DefinitionContext'
context.cpp:2235: error: no matching function for call to 'DefinitionContext<ModuleContext::Private>::DefinitionContext()'
context.cpp:714: note: candidates are: DefinitionContext<T>::DefinitionContext(Definition*) [with T = ModuleContext::Private]
context.cpp:712: note:                 DefinitionContext<ModuleContext::Private>::DefinitionContext(const DefinitionContext<ModuleContext::Private>&)
make[2]: *** [../objects/context.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Is there anyone who knows how to resolve this problem?
Please let me know if you have any idea.
Thanks.

Comment: Seems like you are using the latest version from GitHub. Which gcc & OS version are you using, i.e. what is they output of `gcc --version` and `sw_vers`?

Comment: That' true. I am using the latest version from GitHub.
Here are the outputs:
gcc --version: 
i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
sw_vers: 
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.6.8
BuildVersion:   10K549

Comment: I've just committed this change: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/commit/6db20a8d3cd7d79b3f81f9a6b24585a46f193ea2 Please check if that helps.

Comment: It's working now. Thank you very much for your help. If possible, could you let me know why it crashed before and it works now?

Comment: Nothing crashed, it was just a compiler error, because your (old) compiler couldn't figure out that DefinitionContext was a base class without explicity specifying the template arguments.